# google recaptcha to work with php 5.2

Tags: php, php-5.2, recaptcha

I want to implement [google recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/) with my old website that uses php 5.2 
the problem is that the  [php code](https://github.com/google/recaptcha) that available make use of namespace which is not supported in php 5.2.

Any idea how to do that? or is there any supported code for php 5.2?

Thanks

Comment: if your using a 6 year old php version - your doing it wrong

Comment: [PHP 5.2 reached end-of-life in January 2011.](http://php.net/eol.php) It is not safe to use. Stop.

Comment: i means stop using a dangerously dated php version

Comment: I have no option to do that , it a website that I am trying to troubleshoot